# div with label, input and datepicker button where button is little bellow input

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a problem with my div element wchich contains label, input and button for opening datepicker popup. Button wchich open this one is a little below the input. I'd like to have all elements in one line. I use bootstrap for that. Below is show my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="input-group">
                <label for="usr">Date From:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt1" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="input-group">
                <label for="usr">Date To:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt2" is-open="datepickers.dtSecond" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dtSecond')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could someone help me with that? I would be greatful for helping
Best regards ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making use of Bootstrap's `.form-group` wrapper you can achieve the results you desire:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr" class="control-label">Date From:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt1" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about `.form-group` and a variety of other form-related helper-classes on Bootstrap's documentation page: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms